# arbitrary floating precision number to string

Tags: c, pi, mpfr

I am new to c programming language.
What I am trying to do is to get store pi in arbitary precision and turn that to string.

```
int calculatePIConst (int preciznost)
{
    //init var
    mpfr_t x;
    mpfr_init2 (x, preciznost);
    //populate pi
    mpfr_const_pi (x, MPFR_RNDN);
    //turn to string
    char abc[preciznost];
    int i;
    //error RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped; real time: 90ms; user: 0ms; system: 0ms
    //  mpfr_get_str (abc, i, 50, 50, x, MPFR_RNDN);
    //write pi
    mpfr_printf ("PI = %1.1024RNf\n", x);
    mpfr_clear (x);
    return *abc;
}
```

Here is mpfr lib documentation documentation http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Miscellaneous-Functions

Comment: You have the comment `//turn to string` then the array `char abc[preciznost];` which is not initialised, yet you return the first element's value as the function value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to:

> If *str* is not a null pointer, it should point to a block of storage large enough for the significand, i.e., at least max(*n* + 2, 7). The extra two bytes are for a possible minus sign, and for the terminating null character, and the value 7 accounts for -@Inf@ plus the terminating null character.

Also, I assume you want your result in base 10, not base 50.

Try this:

```
char abc[preciznost + 2]; /* assuming preciznost >= 5 */
  :
mpfr_get_str (abc, i, 10, 50, x, MPFR_RNDN);
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to let the MPFR to allocate the string:

```
char* abc = NULL;
abc = mpfr_get_str (NULL, i, 10, 50, x, MPFR_RNDN);

printf ("PI = %s\n", abc);

mpfr_clear(x);
mpfr_free_str(abc);
```

Also check this member function from [C++ wrapper for the MPFR](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/mpfr/) for example:

```
inline std::string mpreal::toString(const std::string& format) const
{
    char *s = NULL;
    std::string out;

    if( !format.empty() )
    {
        if(!(mpfr_asprintf(&s, format.c_str(), mpfr_srcptr()) < 0))
        {
            out = std::string(s);

            mpfr_free_str(s);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

The thing is to use mpfr_asprintf, it allocates and returns the string automatically (same as mpfr_get_str) but also lets you use the format specification.

Answer (score 0):

What value are you passing for `preciznost`? I see that the calls can handle very large bit precision, and there is a danger that you have broken the stack with the declaration

```
char abc[preciznost];
```

I suggest you allocate memory on the heap instead, remembering to `free()` it later.

```
char *abc = malloc(preciznost);
```

Although it is unclear what you will be using this array for. If it is a char array of `'0'` or `'1'` bit values you will need an extra byte for the `nul` termintor, so

```
char *abc = malloc(preciznost+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The prototype is:

```
char *mpfr_get_str (char *str, mpfr_exp_t *expptr, int b, size_t n, mpfr_t op, mpfr_rnd_t rnd)
```

There are two wrong things in your code:

1. The array is not large enough. See [the answer by squeamish ossifrage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29098551/3782797). But if you choose to use `n` equal to 0, it is better to let MPFR allocate the string (also suggested by Pavel Holoborodko in all cases).
2. The second argument must be a pointer to `mpfr_exp_t`. For instance:

   `mpfr_exp_t e;
   mpfr_get_str (abc, &e, 10, 50, x, MPFR_RNDN);`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Pavel's answer, I created this function to output the string.

```
string Autozoom::mpfrToString(const mpfr_t& in) {
    int decimalLocation;
    char* outChar = NULL;

    mpfr_exp_t mpfrDecimalLocation;
    outChar = mpfr_get_str(NULL, &mpfrDecimalLocation, 10, 0, in, MPFR_RNDN);

    decimalLocation = mpfrDecimalLocation;

    string out(outChar);

    if (out[0] == '-') {
        out.insert(decimalLocation + 1, ".");
    }
    else {
        out.insert(decimalLocation, ".");
    }

    return out;
}
```

This will actually take the number for the decimal point, insert it into a string and return that.